# send "k" key to other window when "a" key is pressed

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to send "k"key to external window by pressing "a" key . 
I have "getasynckeystate" function in my app.

I have tried
"`If getasynckeystate (keys.a)` then
Sendkeys.send("k")" this code in my app but when I press "a" key, the external app shows both "a" and "k". I want to show only "k". So I want to know how to put keypress event in  a timer.

And please tell me how to show only "k" to a external app when I press "a" key.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "eat" a key, you need to use [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319524) is a example.

When the `a` key is detected, Send `k` key and then, `Return -1`

instead of `Return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)`

and the key will be eaten as you wished.

Comment: If you dont mind please give me the full code and thanks for your help